# php can not get the data send by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is the js code, ajax has two arguments, the first is url, 2nd is a object which contains type data and onsuccess. (I didn't use jQuery but the function I define myself, the code is at the end of the question)
I just want to send the 'text' string to php, so is there any problem to do like this? I also have tried change the data to data:  {searchinput:"text"}, but still don't work.

```js
ajax(
    'http://localhost/test.php', 
    {
        type: 'POST',
        data:  "searchinput=text",
        onsuccess: function (responseText, xhr) {
            console.log(responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

this is the php code, sorry for changing the code wrong while pasting it on.

```html
$searchinput = $_POST["searchinput"];
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'text');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "error:can not connect database";
}
$query = "select * from text where data like'".$searchinput."%' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

then the error is

> Undefined index: searchinput

I have search some method like change onsuccess function to setTimeout, and do ajax again, but it doesn't work, just send the data again but the php still can't get the data

this is the ajax function

```js
function ajax(url, options) {
    if (!options.type) {
        options.type = "post"
    };
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(options.type, url, true);
    xhr.send(options.data);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304) {
            options.onsuccess(xhr.responseText, xhr)
        } else {
            options.onfail(xhr.responseText, xhr);
        }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to use {searchinput: text}

Comment: maybe Im wrong, but should your php query not look like `$query = "select * from text where data like'".$searchcon."%' ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you used the ajax wrong, I'm not surprised. There should be a error in the console.

jQuery AJAX is used like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/test.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {searchinput: text},
        success: function (responseText, xhr) {
            console.log(responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

url is a part of the object the ajax expects, so it needs to be inside and not outside of it. Also, data is expecting another object, you gave it a plain string.

Also, as @Muhammad Ahmed stated in his answer, you are using a wrong variable in your php code.

Edit: AJAX in JavaScript without jQuery:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost/test.php', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // worked
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    } else {
      // failed
    }
  }
};
request.send();
request = null;
```

Comment: but I define an ajax function without using jQuery

Comment: @fiona there is no native ajax function in javaScript. You need to use the `XMLHttpRequest` Object in that case, check my updated answer for an ajax without jquery.

Comment: To the guy who downvoted this, care to explain? Or just another tactical downvote?

Comment: @ Y U NO WORK , I didn't paste the ajax function just now but I have it in my js files. In the browers console, the post information is right

Comment: @Y U NO WORK, thx very much, I tired the jQuery and it works, so the there must be some problem in my ajax function. I think the problem is the send(options.data), what should be send in the send()? please..

Answer (score 0):

send data value like below and use `print_r($_POST)` on php page to see values are coming or not

```
$.ajax(

    {   url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
                searchinput:text
             },
        onsuccess: function (responseText, xhr) {
            console.log(responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: @fiona just updated the code if not work than show us your html also

Comment: thx very much, but I just want to send the 'text' string to the php, so is there any relation between the error and html files?

Comment: @fiona i thought u r getting `text` as value from some where!!  is there any error in console???

Comment: there is no error in the console, and the post information is right, if the 'text' have some problem, I think the php can still get the ['searchinput'], I have search this problem long time, maybe I should try the jQuery..sigh

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code you were using ajax in wrong manner. You can learn more about how ajax works and how to code for ajax over http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax( 
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost/test.php',
        data:  {searchinput:text},
        success: function (responseText, xhr) {
            console.log(responseText);
        }
    }
);
```

and within your PHP file you need to update your typo i.e. you were getting value of your **POST** in $searchcon variable

```
$searchcon = $_POST["searchinput"];
^^^^^^^^^^
```

and within your query you were using

```
$query = "select * from text where data like'".$searchinput."%' ";
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it should be like

```
$query = "select * from text where data like'".$searchcon."%' ";
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: **Downvoters atleast post your reason why its been downvoted. Atleast another user let know whats been wrong within this code.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchcon = $_POST["searchinput"];
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'text');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "error:can not connect database";
}
$query = "select * from text where data like'".$searchinput."%' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

In This code there is a mistake on ist line you are using variable $searchcon
and on query you are using $searchinput change ist varaible name to $searchinput instead of $searchcon. and also change your ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/test.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {searchinput: text},
        success: function (responseTxt, xhr) {
            console.log(responseTxt);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

> ```
> var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
> $.ajax({
>         url: 'work.php',
>         data: other_data,
>         type: 'POST',
>         success: function(data){
>             console.log(data);
>         }
>     });
> ```

or

you can also pass the data in url also.
Try the code which suits your requirement.

> ```
> $.ajax({
>         url: 'work.php?index=checkbox&action=empty',
>         type: 'POST',
>         success: function(data){
>             console.log(data);
>         }
>     });
> ```